# How can i access the page table of a process from kernel using a custom syscall?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-management

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, kernel: 4.17.4

I want to access the page table of a process. The idea is, inside a c code I will call a custom Syscall and the syscall will be able to access the page table of the process. How do I design the system call? I'd appreciate any example or related reading materials.

My job is to modify some page table entries (changing some virtual address to physical address mapping) of the page table for a project which I want to do using the syscall.

Comment: hm, Ubuntu 16.04 is probably not the system I'd do development on today, being end-of-life and everything, but that's not important here (it only means *you* need to use outdated tooling on outdated kernels using outdated compilers – but that's mainly an annoyance for you, nothing changing your question). Why don't you look at existing syscalls that do that already? `mmap` is a good choice.

Comment: also, are you sure you want to write a syscall for this? Sounds like something that would very elegantly fit into /proc's procfs, especially since the information on its own memory mappings is already there, in a structured form, for every process to read!

Comment: can i change the mapping from /proc's procfs? Here my task is to change the mapping. To be clear, I want to change the pointer of one virtual address to some another physical address. Using mmap how can this be done, any idea?

Comment: You're in kernel space, you can do anything. So, yes, you should be able to do anything you could with a syscall also through accessing a (pseudo)file on procfs